# How to pass binary data between microservices in Spring Cloud?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, microservices

I'd like to ask. How to pass binary data between microservices in Spring Cloud?

Should (Can) I use @FeignClient or @RibbonClient ? How it should be? I've already read that @FeignClient is not deal with this issue What else? OkHttp?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Cloud integrates with some http clients, like you mentioned. Ribbon has some [non-http clients/transports built in](https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/tree/master/ribbon-transport/src/main/java/com/netflix/ribbon/transport/netty), but I haven't used that and AFIAK, netflix doesn't use them either.

You can use the Spring Cloud [`LoadBalancerClient` interface directly](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_using_the_ribbon_api_directly). It gives you access to a host and port, then you can use any client you want.

```
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    private LoadBalancerClient loadBalancer;

    public void doStuff() {
        ServiceInstance instance = loadBalancer.choose("myService");
        String host = instance.getHost();
        int port = instance.getPort();
        // ... do something with the host and port
    }
}
```

I also did a sample integration with [OkHttp](https://github.com/spring-cloud-incubator/okhttp-ribbon).

Comment: Should service "myService" be annotated as @RibbonClient or anything else ? Since instance.getHost() & instance.getPort() contains wrong host and port :(

Comment: No, `myService` should be registered in eureka. You'd have to tell me more about your setup.